# No such table: mytable in XAML

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am still trying to understand how XAML full works and what you can do with it but in my page I declare a `DataContext` of a `Day` class

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:Day/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

but on the line `<local:Day/>` I get squiggly lines and it says `No such table: Events` (Events is my class that holds information about an object from a sqlite table)

then down lower in my XAML where I use the day I get more lines

```
<Input:RadCalendar x:Name="calendar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                           Height="748" Width="891" SelectionMode="Single" 
                           SelectedDateRange="{Binding SelectedDate, Converter={StaticResource converter}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                           CellStyleSelector="{StaticResource selector}"/>
```

saying `object reference not set to an instance of an object`

this these problems nothing in my designer shows up, its just blank but if I run the application in the simulator it works fine.

what is the cause of these errors?

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is likely because the `Day` object is trying to actually connect to your Database, but failing (at design time).

I'd suggest that you consider adding a check to see if the code is running in `DesignMode` ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.designmode.designmodeenabled)) in your `Day` class so that it skips trying to execute the SQL code (and maybe instead provide demo data as needed).

The second issue is likely similar to the first in that you're trying to bind to a property called `SelectedDate`, and if that's not set either the calendar or the `Converter` is failing when it's `null`.